# Remove class when bottom of div reaches viewport bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to create a parallax type effect where the image follows the user until the end of the content. Currently a class is added when the div reaches the top of the viewport however I am not able to reverse the effect when the div content is scrolled passed.

[Here is a codepen example](http://codepen.io/simonfricker/pen/EPeYJG)

**HTML**

```
<div class="filler">Scroll down</div>
<div class="sticky-stuff"></div>
<div class="content">
  Bacon ipsum dolor amet shankle pancetta bacon beef ribs shank strip steak beef andouille brisket ground round drumstick frankfurter. Beef rump brisket kevin ground round strip steak picanha pancetta andouille pig. Landjaeger pork meatball, turducken leberkas ribeye sausage frankfurter porchetta tongue fatback filet mignon pork belly beef ribs andou leberkas ribeye sausage frankfurter porchetta tongue fatback filet mignon pork belly beef ribs andouille. Biltong fatback swine pancetta salami hamburger, meatloaf short ribs strip steak capicola flank andouille. Tongue pastrami prosciutto capicola. leberkas ribeye sausage frankfurter porchetta tongue fatback filet mignon pork belly beef ribs andouille. Biltong fatback swine pancetta salami hamburger, meatloaf short ribs strip steak capicola flank andouille. Tongue pastrami prosciutto capicola. leberkas ribeye sausage frankfurter porchetta tongue fatback filet mignon pork belly beef ribs andouille. Biltong fatback swine pancetta salami hamburger, meatloaf short ribs strip stea leberkas ribeye sausage frankfurter porchetta tongue fatback filet mignon pork belly beef ribs andouille. Biltong fatback swine pancetta salami hamburger, meatloaf short ribs strip steak capicola flank andouille. Tongue pastrami prosciutto capicola. leberkas ribeye sausage frankfurter porchetta tongue fatback filet mignon pork belly beef ribs andouille. Biltong fatback swine pancetta salami hamburger, meatloaf short ribs strip steak capicola flank andouille. Tongue pastrami prosciutto capicola. leberkas ribeye sausage frankfurter porchetta tongue fatback filet mignon pork belly beef ribs ando leberkas ribeye sausage frankfurter porchetta tongue fatback filet mignon pork belly beef ribs andouille. Biltong fatback swine pancetta salami hamburger, meatloaf short ribs strip steak capicola flank andouille. Tongue pastrami prosciutto capicola.uille. Biltong fatback swine pancetta salami hamburger, meatloaf short ribs strip steak capicola flank andouille. Tongue pastrami prosciutto capicola.k capicola flank andouille. Tongue pastrami prosciutto capicola.ille. Biltong fatback swine pancetta salami hamburger, meatloaf short ribs strip steak capicola flank andouille. Tongue pastrami prosciutto capicola. Chuck venison ball tip boudin capicola t-bone ham hock sirloin pork. Meatloaf t-bone pancetta cupim cow shankle drumstick pork chop corned beef strip steak. Pork chop beef tenderloin kielbasa. Beef ribs beef cow ham hock biltong alcatra kevin picanha fatback pig brisket ground round boudin porchetta rump. Ham hock drumstick andouille filet mignon prosciutto porchetta shoulder kielbasa sirloin, shank swine. Cow biltong jowl, short loin turkey frankfurter flank tri-tip pancetta tenderloin. Rump ground round sirloin, fatback drumstick salami prosciutto picanha. Sausage brisket porchetta, ham pancetta turducken pork chop. Short loin porchetta strip steak, frankfurter landjaeger bresaola hamburger sirloin.
</div>
<div class="filler"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.filler {
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.sticky-stuff {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/yT65RYM.jpg) no-repeat center center / cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

.content {
  width: 400px;
  background: white;
  margin: 50px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

  var size = $(window).height(),
    item = $('.sticky-stuff');

  $(window).scroll(function() {

      var fromtop = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (fromtop > size) item.addClass('sticky');
      else item.removeClass('sticky');

      if (($(".content").offset().top + $(".content").height()) >= $(window).height()) {
        item.removeClass('sticky');
      }

    })
    .resize(function() {
      size = $(window).height();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your JavaScript in the following condition. It is always true:

```
$(".content").offset().top + $(".content").height()) >= $(window).height()
```

It should be

```
$(".content").offset().top + $(".content").height()) < $(window).scrollTop()
```

You can even clarify your JavaScript by having more meaningfull variable names and simpler conditions. For example:

```
var triggerTop = $(".container").offset().top;
var triggerBottom = triggerTop + $(".container").height();
var item = $('.sticky-stuff');

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var curentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var isSticky = curentScroll > triggerTop && curentScroll < triggerBottom
    item.toggleClass('sticky', isSticky);
});
```

You can play with it here http://codepen.io/tzi/pen/xZaxEv

Comment: Thank you, I realise however that I should not be using postion:fixed but rather transfarom:translateY() - How can I do this and make it stop translating when it reaches the bottom of the div?

Or continue to use postion:fixed and then add a margin top?

Comment: I should warn you, trigger a class is a more cheaper thant re-evaluate a transition at every scroll event ;) I think you should stick to `position: fixed`. Otherwise, here is a solution http://codepen.io/tzi/pen/LGJYrN